# Count values of nested array metakey

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, metadata

I want to count how many times an metavalue is inside a certain page (id).
I allready got the metavalue like this:

```
function aantal_reviews_ophalen() {
$get_page_ID = get_queried_object_id();

$get_review_count = get_post_meta( $get_page_ID, $key = 'rwp_rating_0' , $single = false);  

return array_count_values($get_review_count)['343'];
}
```

**343** in this case is the value of the field rating_post_id but not working.

I tried many things but nothing seems to work.

I also tried it with this example:

```
$array = array("Kyle","Ben","Sue","Phil","Ben","Mary","Sue","Ben");
$counts = array_count_values($array);
return $counts['Ben'];
```

Working like a charm but this is because this array is different then the array I got from $get_review_count.

When I `print_r($get_review_count);` I get this as a result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [rating_id] => rwp_rating_5b4da83f6b281 [rating_post_id] => 343 [rating_review_id] => 0 [rating_score] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 3.5 ) [rating_user_id] => 0 [rating_user_name] => Joep van Dongen [rating_user_email] => testmail@gmail.com [rating_title] => Dit is een test beoordeling [rating_comment] => Dit is een test beoordeling [rating_images] => Array ( ) [rating_date] => 1531815999 [rating_status] => published [rating_verified] => [rating_template] => rwp_template_5b16a33aa16b7 [rating_privacy] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [rating_id] => rwp_rating_5bd0271605392 [rating_post_id] => 343 [rating_review_id] => 0 [rating_score] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 5 [2] => 5 ) [rating_user_id] => 4 [rating_user_name] => [rating_user_email] => [rating_title] => Harry de Vries [rating_comment] => Dit is een testreview om te kijken of et werkrty [rating_images] => Array ( ) [rating_date] => 1540368150 [rating_status] => published [rating_verified] => [rating_template] => rwp_template_5b16a33aa16b7 [rating_privacy] => Array ( [t5bab7c0abed1f] => true ) ) )
```

This looks like a nested array but to be honest I have no clue how to retrieve the data that I want.

How can I count how many times [rating_post_id] with value 343 is in this array and return the value?

**EDIT**
Ok, I now used this:

```
echo var_export($get_review_count, true);
```

And this is the what I got back:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'rating_id' => 'rwp_rating_5b4da83f6b281', 'rating_post_id' => 343, 'rating_review_id' => '0', 'rating_score' => array ( 0 => 2.0, 1 => 2.0, 2 => 3.5, ), 'rating_user_id' => 0, 'rating_user_name' => 'Joep van Dongen', 'rating_user_email' => 'dongen.van.joep@gmail.com', 'rating_title' => 'Dit is een test beoordeling', 'rating_comment' => 'Dit is een test beoordeling', 'rating_images' => array ( ), 'rating_date' => 1531815999, 'rating_status' => 'published', 'rating_verified' => false, 'rating_template' => 'rwp_template_5b16a33aa16b7', 'rating_privacy' => array ( ), ), 1 => array ( 'rating_id' => 'rwp_rating_5bd0271605392', 'rating_post_id' => 343, 'rating_review_id' => '0', 'rating_score' => array ( 0 => 5.0, 1 => 5.0, 2 => 5.0, ), 'rating_user_id' => 4, 'rating_user_name' => '', 'rating_user_email' => '', 'rating_title' => 'Harry de Vries', 'rating_comment' => 'Dit is een testreview om te kijken of et werkrty', 'rating_images' => array ( ), 'rating_date' => 1540368150, 'rating_status' => 'published', 'rating_verified' => false, 'rating_template' => 'rwp_template_5b16a33aa16b7', 'rating_privacy' => array ( 't5bab7c0abed1f' => 'true', ), ), )
```

Comment: It's impossible to read that array. Can you var_export it or json_decode it?

Comment: @Andreas That explains a lot... did not know that. I am not familiar with var_export. How can I use this to still get the data I want?

Comment: I don't know, because you have still not edited your answer with the var_export or the json_decode.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, did not understand you but I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have `$get_review_count` array like this :

```
$get_review_count = [
    [
        'rating_id' => 'rwp_rating_5b4da83f6b281',
        'rating_post_id' => 343 ,
        'rating_review_id' => 0 ,
        'rating_score' => [
            '0' => 2 ,
            '1' => 2 ,
            '2' => 3.5 ],
        'rating_user_id' => 0 ,
        'rating_user_name' => 'Joep van Dongen ',
        'rating_user_email' => 'testmail@gmail.com ',
        'rating_title' => 'Dit is een test beoordeling ',
        'rating_comment' => 'Dit is een test beoordeling ',
        'rating_images' => [],
        'rating_date' => 1531815999 ,
        'rating_status' => 'published ',
        'rating_verified' => '',
        'rating_template' => 'rwp_template_5b16a33aa16b7 ',
        'rating_privacy' => []
    ],
    [
        'rating_id' => 'rwp_rating_5b4da83f6b281',
        'rating_post_id' => 343 ,
        'rating_review_id' => 0 ,
        'rating_score' => [
            '0' => 2 ,
            '1' => 2 ,
            '2' => 3.5 ],
        'rating_user_id' => 0 ,
        'rating_user_name' => 'Joep van Dongen ',
        'rating_user_email' => 'testmail@gmail.com ',
        'rating_title' => 'Dit is een test beoordeling ',
        'rating_comment' => 'Dit is een test beoordeling ',
        'rating_images' => [],
        'rating_date' => 1531815999 ,
        'rating_status' => 'published ',
        'rating_verified' => '',
        'rating_template' => 'rwp_template_5b16a33aa16b7 ',
        'rating_privacy' => []
    ],
];
```

Since it's multidimensional array, you could use `array_column` to limit the `'rating_post_id'` column only, then do the `array_count_values` afterwards :

```
echo array_count_values(array_column($get_review_count, 'rating_post_id'))['343'];
```

Comment: Wow, so saved my day! I was stuggling with this for hours but could not find anything that pointed me to this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you combine the array_column with array_intersect you will isolate the full arrays with id 343.

```
$new = array_intersect_key($arr,array_intersect(array_column($arr, 'rating_post_id'), [343]));
var_dump($new);
echo count($new); //2
```

https://3v4l.org/AWDEf

Comment: I tested this, works great too! Stil got one question, I am trying to get the value of "rating_comment" the same way as I get the value of "rating_post_id" but I think I have to get this info another way? Only want to get a single value, set the $single allready to "true" but I think the return code should be different because it is a string. Any idea?

Comment: You mean like this? https://3v4l.org/UcPqH this prints the count and the comments associated with `343`;

Comment: Yes that did the trick, is it also possible to just display one comment instead of all of them? I tried to change the array to single = true but did not work. Have to change the way displaying the array results I gues?

Comment: I use array_values instead of implode, this will reset the indexing of the array, meaning the first will have index 0, the next 1. Then I echo the first. I also included a var_dump to show the contents of $comments https://3v4l.org/pb9lK

Comment: your great! Thanks a lot for the help! I have some more challanges but not going to bother you with it ;) Hopefully I wil figure it out! Once again, thanks a lot!